# what is "that..." referring to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In his book *Unweaving the Rainbow*, Richard Dawkins challenges the view expressed in Romantic poetry **that the desire to analyse the workings of the world through examining its smallest components is merely to make a ‘dull catalogue of common things’**. On the contrary, he says, ‘The wonder of the universe and our place in it is revealed through science in ways otherwise impossible to appreciate or imagine.’ Physiologist Francis Ashcroft, whose research investigates the function of ion channels in the beta cells of the pancreas, says, ‘I am piecing together the puzzle. My aim is to see the interconnectedness of it all – how all the bits fit together to produce something gloriously new.’

Is the emphasised part of the paragraph quoted above Dawkins's belief or the view of Romantic poetry? In other words does the phrase mean:

1. Richard Dawkins challenges the view expressed in Romantic poetry and believes that the desire to analyse the workings of the world through examining its smallest components is merely to make a ‘dull catalogue of common things’.

or

2. Romantic poetry expressed a view that assumes the desire to analyse the workings of the world through examining its smallest components is merely to make a ‘dull catalogue of common things’. Richard Dawkins challenges this view.

Answer (score 1):

The "dull catalogue of common things" language quoted in the paragraph is from John Keats's poem "[Lamia](https://books.google.com/books?id=60KD0XP5UMQC&pg=PA214&dq=%22In+the+dull+catalogue+of+common+things%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HyOaVcqJDMmVyATxja_YBQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22In%20the%20dull%20catalogue%20of%20common%20things%22&f=false)" (written in 1820), which—at least in the section where the line appears—offers a Romantic critique of the supposed mechanistic soullessness of science (in the form of early-nineteenth-century philosophy). Here are the relevant lines from "Lamia":

> ... Do not all charms fly/At the mere touch of cold philosophy?/There was an awful rainbow once in heaven:/We know her woof, her texture; she is given/In the dull catalogue of common things./Philosophy will clip an Angel's wings,/Conquer all mysteries by rule and line,/Empty the haunted air, and gnomèd mine—/Unweave a rainbow, as it erewhile made/The tender-person'd Lamia melt into a shade.

According to the quoted paragraph, Dawkins disputes the notion that science reduces natural phenomena to a "dull catalogue," and instead refers to the universe as a place of "wonders" that science enables us "to appreciate or imagine."

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is Dawkin's reaction to Romantic poetry, so your first interpretation would be my interpretation.

Comment: That is not correct. The first interpretation is not a possible meaning of the sentence as it is written. Also, the author’s name is Dawkins, not Dawkin.